# Substrate - finalized is zero

Tags: substrate, parity, polkadot

```rust
2021-04-11 00:57:24 ✨ Imported #21 (0x5294…9b0d)
2021-04-11 00:57:25  Idle (0 peers), best: #21 (0x5294…9b0d), finalized #0 (0xd6bc…1466), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
2021-04-11 00:57:30  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x52948c20547a22e572dff573fa64aa37321a96e3b3b46c1b6fb4494a7ae19b0d
2021-04-11 00:57:30  Prepared block for proposing at 22 [hash: 0xdddef9d6170c36580077eda654a7d33ce3c4cf8621693862aa0643cd25345bfc; parent_hash: 0x5294…9b0d; extrinsics (1): [0xacae…0b4e]]
2021-04-11 00:57:30  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 22. Hash now 0xe713cbd09829abacd48ad7e9ebb8f4e3f3d76cf86ed39f9cac50fa82ffa8fc15, previously 0xdddef9d6170c36580077eda654a7d33ce3c4cf8621693862aa0643cd25345bfc.
2021-04-11 00:57:30 ✨ Imported #22 (0xe713…fc15)
2021-04-11 00:57:30  Idle (0 peers), best: #22 (0xe713…fc15), finalized #0 (0xd6bc…1466), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
2021-04-11 00:57:35  Idle (0 peers), best: #22 (0xe713…fc15), finalized #0 (0xd6bc…1466), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
2021-04-11 00:57:36  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0xe713cbd09829abacd48ad7e9ebb8f4e3f3d76cf86ed39f9cac50fa82ffa8fc15
2021-04-11 00:57:36  Prepared block for proposing at 23 [hash: 0xb2906c6a7f3be192846e32af9ea51622c46a7205618c69b1f2ce870bc0cd1f95; parent_hash: 0xe713…fc15; extrinsics (1): [0xd4c9…2f72]]
2021-04-11 00:57:36  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 23. Hash now 0x26ca84b6e0e22a8ade2ee767267655b0b1123495a4172fe7d5f001d86dc1d669, previously 0xb2906c6a7f3be192846e32af9ea51622c46a7205618c69b1f2ce870bc0cd1f95.
2021-04-11 00:57:36 ✨ Imported #23 (0x26ca…d669)
2021-04-11 00:57:40  Idle (0 peers), best: #23 (0x26ca…d669), finalized #0 (0xd6bc…1466), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
2021-04-11 00:57:42  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x26ca84b6e0e22a8ade2ee767267655b0b1123495a4172fe7d5f001d86dc1d669
2021-04-11 00:57:42  Prepared block for proposing at 24 [hash: 0x234b5ec82eba845b7a7774dbec0e1d7062266459d4db8ed21047fb6b26726d64; parent_hash: 0x26ca…d669; extrinsics (1): [0x8354…9d72]]
2021-04-11 00:57:42  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 24. Hash now 0x4018329d3d0fbbfeb1ef0bbd470f34326d617c84c852b56c19382b000343149a, previously 0x234b5ec82eba845b7a7774dbec0e1d7062266459d4db8ed21047fb6b26726d64.
2021-04-11 00:57:42 ✨ Imported #24 (0x4018…149a)
2021-04-11 00:57:45  Idle (0 peers), best: #24 (0x4018…149a), finalized #0 (0xd6bc…1466), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
```

Following [this tutorial](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/start-a-private-network/customchain), I deploy a single node in local(custom pallet_aura and pallet_grandpa in GenesisConfig). best is right, but finalized is always `#0`. Any ideas on this?

ps: substrate version: 3.0

Comment: Fixed by restarting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need at least two nodes to get finalization. Deploy Bob and it will work ;).